# foreach loop with 3 variables

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

i have 3 txt files so in each row they have one sentences and i want to print them

```
$a = '1.txt';
$b = '2.txt';
$c = '3.txt';

$a1= file($a);
$b1= file($b);
$c1= file($c);

$id=1;

echo ' id: '.$id++. 'lang1: ' . $a1. 'lang2:' . $b1. 'lang3:' . $c1 .'<br>' ;
```

so result should be

id: **1**  lang1: **first row from 1.txt**  lang2:**first row from 2.txt** 
   lang3:**first row from 3.txt**

id: **2**  lang1: **second row from 1.txt**  lang2:**second row from 2.txt** 
   lang3:**second row from 3.txt**

id: **3**  lang1: **third row from 1.txt**  lang2:**third row from 2.txt** 
   lang3:**third row from 3.txt**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how to do it:

```
$a = 'file1.txt';
$b = 'file2.txt';
$c = 'file3.txt';

$a1 = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents($a));
$b1 = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents($b));
$c1 = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents($c));

for($id = 1; $id <= 3; $id++) {
    $line = $id - 1;
    echo "id: {$id} lang1: {$a1[$line]} lang2 {$b1[$line]} lang3: {$c1[$line]} <br>"; 
}
```

Comment: it works just  added some " "
    echo "id: {".$id."} lang1: {".$a1[$line]."} lang2 {".$b1[$line]."} lang3: {".$c1[$line]."} <br>";

Answer (score 0):

All Should be:

```
$a = '1.txt';
$b = '2.txt';
$c = '3.txt';

$a1= file($a, 'r');
$b1= file($b, 'r');
$c1= file($c, 'r');

$id=1;

while(($a_line = fgets($a1)) !== false) {
    $b_line = fgets($b1);
    $c_line = fgets($c1);
    echo ' id: '.$id++. 'lang1: ' . $a_line . 'lang2:' . $b_line . 'lang3:' . $c_line .'<br>' ; 
}
```

You should also close the files:

```
fclose($a1);
fclose($b1);
fclose($c1);
```

Also, this will only work if you have the same amount of lines in each file.

Comment: while(list(, $a2) = each($a1) && list(, $b2) = each($b1) && list(, $c2) = each($c1))
   this print just  $c2      so $a2 and $b2 are blanks

Comment: @Gloytoshtyqo just fixed my answer, have a nother look.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file1 = '1.txt';
$file2 = '2.txt';
$file3 = '3.txt';

$handle1 = fopen($file1, 'rb');
$handle2 = fopen($file2, 'rb');
$handle3 = fopen($file3, 'rb');

$id = 1;

while (($a = fgets($handle1)) && ($b = fgets($handle2)) && ($c = fgets($handle3))) {
    echo 'id: ' . $id++ . 'lang1: ' . $a . 'lang2:' . $b . 'lang3:' . $c .'<br>';
}

fclose($handle1);
fclose($handle2);
fclose($handle3);
```

This will read line by line from the files and print the result you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to:

1. Open the 3 files
2. Read the first line of each file
3. Output the the data in the format required
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for the other lines

One option for opening a file: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

One option for reading the next line from a file: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

fgets will return false when the end of file is reached, so you can base your loop on that.

What have you tried already?